# Spring boot and configuration profile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application with some configuration.
I want to specify different configuration values, for `dev` and `production`.
My `application.properties` file look like this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://devhost:devport/devschema
spring.datasource.username=devuser
spring.datasource.password=mypwd
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

This file is in my git repo on Openshift. Everytime I commit, Openshift start to deploy the application, so I need the `application.properties` with the correct values.
Is it possible to use something like profiles to change the configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create different property files for different profiles using `application-{profile}.properties` format, e.g. `application-dev.properties` for `dev`, and put your profile specific configurations in them. Then when you're running the spring boot application, activate your intended profile using the `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` environment variable or `spring.profiles.active` system property.

Since you're using Openshift, you can export the envirnemnt variable in the `build` file in the `.openshift/action_hooks` directory. Something like this:

```
export JAVA_OPTS_EXT=-Dspring.profiles.active="dev"
```

The better approach is to use `rhc env set` command for enabling one specific profile:

```
rhc env set SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev -a App_Name
```

You can read more about using environment variables in openshift [here](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-environment-variables.html#custom-variables).

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `spring.profiles.active` Spring property to pick which`application-[environment].properties` file to use.  Then create multiple files, one for each environment.  To set the environment just pass this `--spring.profiles.active=development` in your Java arguments.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can do this.

1. Using maven profiles and resource plugins to provide environment or profile specific properties  by replacing properties in your `application.properties` with your profile specific set up.

   [This will help you getting started](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/tips-and-tricks/creating-profile-specific-configuration-files-with-maven/)
2. Using Spring boots build in support for [Externalizing properties environment specific](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties)